# How can I make 2 divs be next to each other?

Tags: html, css, position

I need to make navbar on the left side of the screen and text div to start right next to the navbar. I only managed to make the text div go all the way to the right side of the screen.
So far I have this:

HTML

```
<head>

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "styles.css">
<title>Homepage</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id = "header">
    <h1>Homepage - origins of World Wide Web and the Internet</h1>
</div>
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div id = "navbar">
        <ul>
        <li><a class = "active" href="index.html">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">INTERNET PIONEERS</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">HTTP</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">TERMINOLOGY</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">REFERENCES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id = "text">
        <h2>World Wide Web</h2>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {


width: 97%;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid white;  
  margin: 20px;
}

#header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  background: #600202;
  z-index: -1;
}

#header h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}



#navbar {
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin:5px;
}

#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1; 
    position: fixed; 
    overflow: auto;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 3%;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

#navbar li a.active {
    background-color: #600202;
    color: white;
}


#navbar li {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

#navbar li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

#text {
    border:1px solid black;

}
```

Comment: You should not use `position:absolute;` here , float or display can be much more efficient.

Comment: But that position:absolute; is for the header div and shouldn't have anything to do with the content beneath it? Or am i wrong

Comment: you are right, i had a too quick look, you may use box-shadow also and drop this absolute pseudo :) ( i just noticed i missed part of your css too my bad connexion )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by Javier, the problem exists due to a mix of `position:fixed` and `float:left`, the width in percentage is not calculated correctly because the element is removed from the document flow.

There are some issues with the code that we need to take care of first:

1.) The `position:fixed` is part of `#navbar ul` but in case you would scroll, the navbar container would also scroll along with the text, the fixed navigation would then be scrolling along with its parent container.

2.) The width is defined in the `ul` element (preventing elements to stretch to their appropriate length), the element itself is positioned fixed, that's why the parent element does not have a width itself (as the element is not rendered as part of the surrounding document flow), that's why the `#text` element is located below the `#navbar` element when using `float:left`

**One solution ...**

... might be to move the `position: fixed` to the `#navbar` element, then define a fixed left margin for the `#text` element:

```
#text {
  margin-left: 240px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#navbar {
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 220px;
  position: fixed;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 3%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I created a fiddle containing the complete change [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/b2kn552e/3/).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir  :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with the code Javier Rey wrote, and it worked exactly the way you want. Try temporarily removing the styles related to nav and the div, its because of the margins and padding.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navbar {
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin:5px;
    float: left;
}

#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*width: 15%;*/
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    overflow: auto;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 3%;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#text {
    border:1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but than the text div goes beneath the navigation bar.

Comment: The rule '#navbar ul' is set to position 'fixed' with width '15%'. Remove those (I updated the answer).

Comment: I was trying to help

Comment: @JavierRey you were on the right track, but I think the author wanted to maintain a fixed navigation. Problem is that the author's code is not properly structured (rules applied on the wrong elements), that's why the float did not work as expected.